# Android: pop-up dialog triggered by Alarm.manager in an app should appear on the screen even if this app is not active or not running at all

Tags: android, dialog, popup, alarmmanager

I am developing an android app that uses the AlarmManager, PendinIntent and BroadcastReceiver to fire a pop-up dialog (which is created using Dialogfragment). It works fine as long as this app is active (on screen).

I need this dialog to pup-up also if another app is active, better say also if no app is active. Similar to an AlarmClock application.

What is the proper way to do achieve that?

The method initiating the AlarmManager:

```
logButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ScheduledReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
        long interval = 3600 * 1000;
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
            }});
```

The BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class ScheduledReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                Intent scheduledIntent = new Intent(context, TransparentAlertActivity.class);
                scheduledIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(scheduledIntent);
    }
}
```

And the TransparentAlertActivity (appears transparent withthe dialog being in front) with the dialog() called in its onCreate() to show the dialog that extends DialogFragment:

```
public class TransparentAlertActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public static Intent getIntent(@NonNull Context context) {
        return new Intent(context, MedicationListActivity.class);
    }

    private MedicationListViewModel viewModel;
    private boolean isActive;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_transparent_alert);
        viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MedicationListViewModel.class);
        Log.w("myApp", "in onCreate before inActive() called isActive =" +isActive);
        isActive();
        dialog();
    }

    public void isActive(){
        isActive = viewModel.isMedListActive();
        Log.w("myApp", "in isActiveMethod isActive =" +isActive);
    }

    private void dialog(){
        if(isActive){
            Log.w("myApp", "in dialog and isActive =" +isActive);
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            MedicationDetailsDialogFragment medicationDetailsDialogFragment =
                    MedicationDetailsDialogFragment.createInstance("You need to take your medication now!", "OK", "NEVER MIND");

            medicationDetailsDialogFragment.setOption1ClickListener(dialogView -> {
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                startActivity(MedicationListActivity.getIntent(this));
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            });
            medicationDetailsDialogFragment.setOption2ClickListener(dialogView -> {
                finish();
            });

           medicationDetailsDialogFragment.show(fm, "Medication");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the dialog pops-up only when the app is active, on screen. If it is in the background, then the pop-up does not show up until the app is going to be activated again

Answer (score 0):

Try these :

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

And add this permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31440994/14187529

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it did not help.